# Controlling multiple stepper motors non-simultaneously

Tags: stepper, stepper-motor

I want to control multiple stepper motors one after another and at different speeds/directions. I am using the ULN2003 driver and the stepper has 5 coils.

My current code for controlling one motor is:

```cpp
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 500;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
// for your motor

// initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 10, 9, 11);


void setup() {
  // set the speed at 60 rpm:
  myStepper.setSpeed(50);
  // initialize the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // step one revolution  in one direction:
  Serial.println("clockwise");
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);

  // step one revolution in the other direction:
  Serial.println("counterclockwise");
  myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);
}
```

How would I define each stepper motor differently?

Sorry if I have not asked the question properly. I will try to clarify as time goes on.

Comment: How about multiple variables of the type Stepper, each representing one stepper motor? Do you understand how the code above works?

Comment: @chrisl Yes, I do understand how the code works. I just want to know how to control two different stepper motors. For example, above we have a stepper motor being defined as myStepper.... Oh, do I just have to replace ‘myStepper’ with ‘Stepper2’? Right??

Comment: Exactly. Each Stepper variable controls 1 motor. That should work.

Comment: just a note: that is a `Stepper object`, not a Stepper variable

Answer (score 1):

Like @chris! suggested, you could include two Stepper variables. So in the line where you were initializing the variable, you could instead have:

```
Stepper steppermotor1(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 10, 9, 11);

Stepper steppermotor2(stepsPerRevolution, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

and then continue on with the code for speed, rotation and so on for each motor.

Comment: just realized you got your answer after reading through the comments. Never mind then. Thanks :)